# How to pattern-match Class[X] for different X?

Tags: scala, types

I want to check the type of the parameters of a method, but I don't know the best way to do this. See my code:

```
class X {
    def x(a: Int, b: String) {}
}

val methods = classOf[X].getDeclaredMethods
methods map { m =>
    m.getParameterTypes.toList map { t =>
        println(t.getName)
        // I don't know how to write the following
        if ( the type of t is Int) { do something} 
        else if( the type of t is String ) { do something}
        else { }
    }
}
```

Please note the comment in the code. I don't know how to check the types in scala way.

I've tried:

```
t match {
    case _:String => println("### is a string")
    case _:Int => println("### is an int")
    case _ => println("### ?")
}
```

But it can't be compiled.

I can use java-way to check:

```
if (t.isAssignableFrom(classOf[String])) // do something
else if(t.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Int])) // do something
else {}
```

It seems we should use it in scala, right?

---

UPDATE:

If I want to use `match`, I should write like this:

```
t match {
     case i if i.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Int]) => println("### is an Int")
     case s if s.isAssignableFrom(classOf[String]) => println("### is a String")
     case _ => println("###?")
}
```

Is it the best answer?

Comment: What do you mean by '+>' in the last line ?

Comment: '+>' is probably a typo and should read '=>'

Comment: It's a typo, I just fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could make it work with t as a type by defining the cases as constants. It wouldn't compile with the class literals as the case expression. Try:

```
val S = classOf[String]
val I = classOf[Int]
t match {
    case S => println("### is a string")
    case I => println("### is an int")
    case _ => println("### ?")
}
```

Comment: It still can't be compiled here. Because `t` here is a `Class`, not an normal instance.

Comment: Note that this does not work in the case that `S` and `I` are differently-parametrized instances of the same type e.g. `S = classOf[List[String]]` and `I = classOf[List[Int]]`

Comment: The best I could do was: val L = classOf[::[_]] which allowed case L to match the immutable list (scala.collection.immutable.::). Unfortunately the generic type seems to be erased at runtime, so ::[Anything] would match ::[AnythingElse]. I think Kevin Wright is onto a more promising idea with manifests, for anything more than the simple cases.

Comment: I managed to make that oneliners using guards: `case x if x == classOf[String]`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ClassManifest.fromClass` to correctly handle the coercion of primitives to AnyVals, and any other such troubles you might have encountering boxed vs unboxed types when getting funky with reflection.

Like this:

```
import reflect.ClassManifest

class Wibble { def method(a:Int, b: String) = () }

for(method <- classOf[Wibble].getDeclaredMethods; paramType <- method.getParameterTypes) {
  ClassManifest.fromClass(paramType) match {
    case m if m <:< ClassManifest.Int => println("Interiffic")
    case m if m <:< ClassManifest.Float => println("Floaty, like butterflies")
    case m if m <:< ClassManifest.Double => println("Or Quits...")
    //todo: all the other AnyVal types...
    case m if m <:< classManifest[String] => println("bleeding edge physics, yeah baby!")
    //...and a default condition
  }
}
```

Comment: @Keven, thank you, but I have to say, `<:<` is too difficult for me now :(

Comment: @freewend - It's just a method on `ClassManifest` to check for a subtype relationship. Nothing tricky :)

Comment: @freewend - you can also just use `==` instead of `<:<` if you prefer. It won't catch subclasses, but in this example you don't need to catch subclasses anyway.